# hiera dealing with undefined variables in erb templates

Tags: puppet, hiera

I start using hiera for environment  or machine specific variables but I am facing an issue when variable is not found nowhere. Desired behaviour is that shouldn't be included into template. 
I did following:
In my manifest code

```
$yarn_app_mapreduce_am_command_opts=hiera('yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts',undef)
```

and in erb template I have:

```
<% if !@yarn_app_mapreduce_am_command_opts.nil? %>   
    <property>
    <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts</name>
    <value><%= @yarn_app_mapreduce_am_command_opts %></value>
  </property>
<%end %>
```

According to the documentation [here](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/templating.html#testing-for-undefined-variables) safest is to test on nil. I tried several variants but non of them worked.

Could someone help?

Comment: What is the result of the above code? What is your master version?

Comment: Property specification is every time included (even I tried opposite logic). Using puppet 3.4.2 but ideally we would like to keep compatibility even with 2.7 if possible. I tried several conditions(including those from puppet doc attached) and result was the same. I found various references and the only difference was -%> at the tag end, not sure what is the meaning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with the `hiera()` function. I checked with the following manifest.

```
$without_hiera = undef
$with_hiera = hiera('undefined_key', undef)

$no_hiera_template = 'Without Hiera: <% if @without_hiera.nil? %>nil<% else %>not nil: "<%= @without_hiera %>"<% end %>'
$hiera_template = 'With Hiera: <% if @with_hiera.nil? %>nil<% else %>not nil: "<%= @with_hiera %>"<% end %>'

notify {
    'hiera':
        message => inline_template($hiera_template);
    'no_hiera':
        message => inline_template($no_hiera_template);
}
```

This yields:

```
Notice: Without Hiera: nil
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Notify[no_hiera]/message: defined 'message' as 'Without Hiera: nil'
Notice: With Hiera: not nil: ""
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Notify[hiera]/message: defined 'message' as 'With Hiera: not nil: ""'
```

The issue is known and has been [discussed at length](https://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/20923), but no acceptable fix has come forth yet. The problem is reproducible with the current `master` and `puppet-4` branches.

Seeing as this will be difficult to fix, you are obviously in need of a workaround. The possibilities depend on your data.

1. If a value of boolean `false` (note that this is different from the String `"false"`) is not ever sensible for your keys, you can make `false` the default and just test `<% if ! @value -%>` in your templates.
2. If the empty String is not ever a sensible value, you can make that the default, and test for it using `<% if ! @value.to_s.empty? -%>`
3. Finally, it might be possible for you to write your own wrapper around the hiera function, which overwrites an arbitrary default such as `__KEY_NOT_FOUND__` to `nil`. Your mileage may vary. See the bug report for some pointers to previous work that may be of help.

It may also be helpful to find out whether one of the related bugs was moved to [Jira](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/), and to leave a vote and a note there that this is still an issue with Hiera.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer! Is there any difference between -%> and %> as a tag end?

Comment: BTW: @value.empty? didn't worked for me in a case when value were defined as a number in hiera and I was getting error in a sense that function empty? not defined.

Comment: Good point! I shall amend my answer to include `to_s` in that "pattern". :-)